# jQuery help : click the button and pop up a division/window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Click a button and it will appear a division/window above that current page to upload file.

How can i do this with jQuery ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is the example for popup window over the current page [http://blog.zen-dreams.com/blog-en/2009/06/09/creating-a-popup-window-with-jquery/](http://blog.zen-dreams.com/blog-en/2009/06/09/creating-a-popup-window-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<input type="submit" id="clickme"> </input>
<div id="divtobeshown" style="display:none">
    <input type="file" />
</div>
<html>
```

Js:

```
$("#clickme").live("click", function()
{
$("#divtobeshown").show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/anilkamath87/cfFkd/